# Why this command "google-auth" works in the terminal but not from bash script?

Tags: bash

I have installed libpam-google-authenticator and freeradius on server ubuntu 16.0405.  Everything works good, except for if I use the command google-auth in bash script I get a error message "google-auth: command not found"
But the same works if I put it on terminal directly.

```
#!/bin/bash  
google-auth
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to accurately answer your question.  Based on intuition I would say that your $PATH when running the script doesn't properly include the google-auth executable.  Try running `type google-auth` and go from there.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it without the $PATH (i.e #!/bin/bash), but still the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a bash script.

To make it a bash script, your first line needs to include a "#" as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
google-auth
```

Also, you need to ensure that the script is executable:

```
chmod +x yourscript.sh
```

Hopefully that will solve your problem.

As per the comments below, it seems like the command "google-auth" was an alias which wasn't being established in the child shell.

Comment: Well all that was done in the first place mate. I included the # sign in the question but for some reason it was not displayed. Also the script is executable.

Comment: Ah, I see you've updated the question to reflect that. Another thing to try is try running it with the -x option?
i.e. bash -x yourscipt.sh

Also, if you put other commands in, do they execute (e.g. put in an ls -l).

Also, could you post what your script actually does? i.e. are there any errors displayed, what happens when you run it with bash -x etc?

Comment: Are you running your script from the terminal?
Or are you running it in the background via a scheduled (e.t. at / cron or something else)?
The reason i ask is because the $PATH supplied by, for example, cron is not normally the same as your regular user's path.
Also, perhaps put an echo of the path in your script e.g. echo PATH=$PATH

Comment: Thank you all I had it resolved google-auth was alias name hence the error.

Comment: Hi Raj, I'm glad you worked it out.
I recommend answering your own question with that solution (discovery) and close this question.